# adb command doesn't work in MAC

Tags: android, adb

I installed the ADT for android and set the path of the of the sdk platform tools in .profile and .bash-profile
but still the adb command says not found

Comment: Did you restart bash since you changed its dotfiles?  Also, what happens if you try to invoke adb by its full path name?

Comment: set up your PATH variables

Comment: I set up my path variables in .profile and also .bash-profile. I closed the terminal and opened again, if thats what restarting means. Full path works fine

Comment: export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/sweety/Documents/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platform-tools

Comment: after i restarted it works….