# Error in .bash_profile to add Android ADB on mac

Tags: android, macos, bash

I have been reading the answers here but I am making a mistake somewhere, I think it is my path.

In the questions that I looked at such as

- [-bash: android: command not found on Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19832803/bash-android-command-not-found-on-mac-osx)
- [adb command doesn't work in MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22236258/adb-command-doesnt-work-in-mac)

they discussed paths. I tried that but was not working. I even thought that perhaps I just needed to restart bash as they said. So I saw [how-do-i-reload-bashrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518127/how-do-i-reload-bashrc-without-logging-out-and-back-in). But still when I run `adb devices` I get this error of.

```
-bash: adb: command not found
```

I then found this tutorial [How to Install & Setup ADB on Mac OS X](https://seo-michael.co.uk/how-to-setup-adb-on-os-x/) which had a slightly different approach by copying the ADB to a different directory in Documents. So now I have a duplicate directory of the Android SDK which just sounds like a bad idea. And that directory is now in my own user directory. Not in the main Applications folder where I have Android Studio.

Here is my code so far. I know that I need that first `{PATH}` But which one?

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/juangallardo/Documents/android
```

And it fits into the rest of my file like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thtat's because the adb is not in the android folder, you need to go into the platform-tools folder of the android SDK, also make sure to reopen a new termina to load the .bash_profile...

You need to add a path like this:

> /Users/YourUser/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools

Hope it helps!

Regards!